# How to use angular ui select with valid markup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to use [Angular UI Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) with a valid markup that will pass the W3 validator instead of the `<ui-select>` tag. How can I do that?

There is an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview is it possible to have it but using something like a `<select>` tag?

Comment: not too sure if angular is the tool for you if you want it W3 compliant

Comment: for angular attributes, I can add a data- prefix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the Angular UI Select source code is [hard-coded to work with non-standard elements](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/select.js#L602).

You could modify the source to have it work with divs or similar. It would not be possible, however, to make it work with standard <select> elements, since the browser and the DOM don't expose enough customizable end points.